# Kettle, "NullPointerException" in Step: Java Script

Tags: java, kettle

Recently, take use of Kettle for ETL.

[image: screenshot of the error]

While when trying out the STEP: java script, Kettle will throw out NullPointerException as the pic shows.

The script step follows the step of reading from database with output.
Using the lastest stable version of Kettle : pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386
PC Info : Win 8.1   64 bit

Is anybody has solve such problem? Thanks for sharing the solutions!

Add Comments:
Some other steps could take place the Java functions.. It can work without it. It crashes when I try to use the input fields on the sidebar, but it is OK with manual input. The previous step is query from database with output fields.

Comment: Does your transformation work without the JavaScript? The JavaScript crashes as soon as you open it?

Comment: What step is before JavaScript Step? "Getting fields ...please wait" - means kettle can't get row metadata from previous step.

Comment: Yes, I can use several steps to take place the Java .. It can work without it. It crashes when I try to use the input fields on the sidebar, it is OK with manual input. The previous step is query from database with output